How can I get the last specific character from a UDF with a regex in PySpark?
I am trying to use a regular expression (regex) to extract the last character from a PySpark DataFrame in order to perform some data cleanup and parsing into columns.
Currently, I am using a UDF (User Defined Function), where one of the fields will be user input. I'm specifically looking for a way to capture the last closing square bracket ]. I've tried a few different approaches but keep getting stuck, so I would appreciate any assistance you can provide. Thank you in advance!
sample text:
* the cat in the hat is fat\r\n
* synnopsis -- hey the cat who is wearing the hat is getting to big for its outfit as evidenced by this photo [img123123.png] \r\n
* please get a new cat, or a new hat I would suggest something like this [newhatforcat.jpg]
signed
bob <bob@somecompany.com>

These body texts get put into a Python list, and I an doing a pyspark function to split on the last ].  This is a problem if someone uses the ] char or outlook decides to put the [imgblala.jpg] inside the raw text, then all my columns get over written.
I tried inserting a regex that works on regex101 to capture the last ], which should be the ] from the python list but I am getting an undefined, or else if I just use the ] to split, we would split on the img123123.jpg.
When putting regex into a split, is there some specific char I need to use before the delim column?  Here is an example of what I am trying to do.
from pyspark.sql.functions import split

one_value = "['to@abc.com', '[* the cat in the hat is fat\r\n* synnopsis -- hey the cat who is wearing the hat is getting to big for its outfit as evidenced by this photo [img123123.png] \r\n* please get a new cat, or a new hat I would suggest something like this [newhatforcat.jpg]\r\nsigned\r\nbob <bob@somecompany.com>]', 'from@abc.com']"


df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[(one_value,),], schema='emailobj: string')

df = df.withColumn("to", split(df["emailobj"], "]").getItem(0)) \
                     .withColumn("from", split(df["emailobj"], "]").getItem(2)) \
                     .withColumn("body", split(df["emailobj"], r"[^]]*]$").getItem(3)) \
                     .withColumn("messageid", split(df["emailobj"], "]").getItem(4)) \
                     .withColumn("subject", split(df["emailobj"], "]").getItem(6))

I either get an undefined or the split doesnt split on the last ].  This regex seems to work on regex101 as a java regex. Here is a link: (https://regex101.com/r/1ZbVG3/2) Do I need to do something for spark to see it correctly?

Please don't tag your titles. See [ask]. Feel free to revise further if mine isn't right.

Confused, what does a regex have to do with your use of split?

hello Andrew, well I was trying to account for all huma possibilities what they write  inside the text field.  I was using split from a UDF. The other fields are split on ].  I am still kinda new to spark and pyspark so if i am doing it wrong -- open to suggestions

Can you provide an example? I've updated the code. Fix the value of one_value in the code with a realistic sample.

@Kashyap -- updated as requested, if this is not what you are asking please let me know :) Appreciate your help

Assuming values in that column are always well formatted arrays, you can just use eval() to convert it to an array. Note the little trick about encode('unicode_escape') to address the fact that you have unescaped \n\r in the body,
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType, StructField, StructType
>>>
>>>
...     StructField("to", StringType(), False),
...     StructField("body", StringType(), False),
...     StructField("from", StringType(), False),
... ])
>>>
>>> email_split = F.udf(lambda s: eval(s.encode('unicode_escape')), return_type)
>>> one_value = "['to@abc.com', '[* the cat in the hat is fat\r\n* synnopsis -- hey the cat who is wearing the hat is getting to big for its outf
it as evidenced by this photo [img123123.png] \r\n* please get a new cat, or a new hat I would suggest something like this [newhatforcat.jpg]\r\n
signed\r\nbob <bob@somecompany.com>]', 'from@abc.com']"
>>>
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[(one_value,),], schema='emailobj: string')
>>> df = df.withColumn('emailobj_split', email_split(df.emailobj))
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- emailobj: string (nullable = true)
 |-- emailobj_split: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- to: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- body: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- from: string (nullable = false)

>>> df2 = df.select('emailobj_split.*')
>>> df2.show()
+----------+--------------------+------------+
|        to|                body|        from|
+----------+--------------------+------------+
|to@abc.com|[* the cat in the...|from@abc.com|
+----------+--------------------+------------+

>>> df2.show(truncate=False)
+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------+------------+
|to        |body

               |from        |
+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------+------------+
|to@abc.com|[* the cat in the hat is fat\r\n* synnopsis -- hey the cat who is wearing the hat is getting to big for its outfit as evidenced by th
is photo [img123123.png] \r\n* please get a new cat, or a new hat I would suggest something like this [newhatforcat.jpg]\r\nsigned\r\nbob <bob@so
mecompany.com>]|from@abc.com|
+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------+------------+
>>>

email_split = F.udf(lambda s: eval(s.encode('unicode_escape')), return_type)

# line above is a short version of elaborate one below. 
# You can use the one below, if you want more than one liner lambda
# as your implementation.

@F.udf(returnType=return_type)
def email_split(s):
    arr = eval(s.encode('unicode_escape'))
    return arr



thanks @kashyap -- will check and get back to you.
yes what i am doing is a UDF into a python list.  The issue was happening when there was another ] char like the image [whatever.jpg] and would split on that.
